# Django - Is it necessary to clean BooleanField in forms?

Tags: django

As the title says.  BooleanField are simply displayed as checkboxes - is it necessary to clean them before processing them?  Or is cleaning only necessary to fields like CharField?

Comment: Short answer: Yes.

Comment: Note, you call `form.is_valid()` and Django validates all form fields. So excluding any field from validation means writing more (and redundant) code. The displayed form field isn't important here. The data that is posted to your view is important. It is super easy to create a post request containing other data. So yes, always validate your form.

Answer (score 0):

By default, each field class in Django is required. If you have not defined BooleanField with required=False, and you do not pass any value to the BooleanField, clean() method will raise the ValidationError.

You can pass required=False when defining BooleanField.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    myfield = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```